# How to call i18next.tr function with different locale?

Tags: i18next

I have two folders, fi and sv. Both have their own translation.json files. Calling i18n.tr(text) function works fine, it returns the text from the current language's .json file.

However, sometimes I need to access text from the .json files of different locales. Does i18n allow to pass language as a parameter? Is calling setLocale(language) necessary in order to retrieve text from other language's .json files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `{lng: 'sv'}` to the `t` function in order to override the current language.

```js
t('MY.KEY', {lng: 'other-locale'})
```